# use ctypes call windows api function to set color profile

Tags: python, winapi, controlpanel, color-management

I am trying to use ctypes to call windows api function to set color profile. According to the document, I have to first install color profile and then associate it to the monitor. In my case, I want to associate to the display 1. mscms.AssociateColorProfileWithDeviceW(None,profile_path,Device.DeviceName)  return 0. I check the color management. the profile is not associated. Does someone know what's wrong here? Thanks!

here is the code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import win32api as w
import win32con as c 
mscms = ctypes.CDLL("Mscms.dll")
profile_path = r'C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color\test.icm'
#install profile
res = mscms.InstallColorProfileW(None,profile_path)
Device = w.EnumDisplayDevices(None,0,0)
associateProfile = mscms.AssociateColorProfileWithDeviceW(None,profile_path,Device.DeviceName)
print('associateProfile: ',associateProfile)
```

Comment: I recommend researching which win32 library functions you'd need to be able to do this programmatically, then learning how to use ctypes in Python to run those functions, and then if you run into any problems which you absolutely cannot solve, post a detailed, specific question on this site. We expect you to have done a lot more research on things before posting. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wcs/profile-management-functions) may be of some help, here is a list of functions you can use to manage color profiles.

Specifically, [InstallProfileColorW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icm/nf-icm-installcolorprofilew) might be what you're looking for.

I don't think this is currently supported in [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) and would require you to either use `ctypes` or `cffi` yourself to create the particular bindings, or perhaps write a Python extension that does this for you.

Comment: thanks, I have done some research in pywin32. Couldn't find any. good to know this. maybe I should use ctypes . Thanks!